# Button in TextInput in react native

Tags: react-native

How can I insert and style a button in text input in react native like this:
[image]

Can I use any code like this?

```
<Textinput>
   <Button></Button>
</Textinput>
```

Comment: So you want a touch on the search icon to call onSubmit?

Comment: Yes, I want that.

Comment: in react native header with search icon if tap on search i need to open input field based on boolean value help me

Answer (score 10):

Sorry for the delay, but something like this should work:

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'row', width: window.width, margin: 10, padding:4, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center', borderWidth:4, borderColor:'#888, borderRadius:10, backgroundColor:'#fff'}}>
  <View style={{flex:4}}>
    <TextInput
        onChangeText = {(textEntry) => {this.setState({searchText: textEntry})}}
        style={{backgroundColor:'transparent'}}
        onSubmitEditing = {()=>{this.onSubmit(this.state.searchText)}}
      />
  </View>
  <View style={{flex:1}}>
    <Button onPress={ () => this.onSubmit(this.state.searchText) }>
        <Image source={ require('../images/searchImage.png') } style={ { width: 50, height: 50 } } />
    </Button>
  </View>
</View>
```

where you adjust the size based on your image and Button is imported like:

```
import Button from '../components/Button';
```

I like to keep the button in an external folder, where it is like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

class Button extends Component {
  handlePress(e) {
    if (this.props.onPress) {
        this.props.onPress(e);
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={ this.handlePress.bind(this) }
            style={ this.props.style } >
            <Text>{ this.props.children }</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
export default Button;
```

Good luck!

Comment: This doesn't put the magnifying glass icon inside of the text input box.

Comment: yeah you should have really included a screenshot of what this looks like. There's no way this code produces the desired result.

Answer (score 5):

wrapping both in a `View` with `flexDirection:row` should get you there.

If you want to get more advanced, you could look at the [react-native-textinput-effects](https://github.com/halilb/react-native-textinput-effects) package that will give you some very nicely styled inputs.

Answer (score 4):

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
    <View>
      <TextInput
          style={{alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center',backgroundColor:'white'}}
          value = {this.state.searchString}
          onChangeText = {(searchString) => {this.setState({searchString})}}
          placeholder = 'Search'
          keyboardType = 'web-search'
          onSubmitEditing = {()=>{this._fetchResults()}}
          ref = 'searchBar'
          />
    </View>
    <TouchableHighlight style={{alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}} onPress = {()=>{this._fetchResults()}} underlayColor = 'transparent'>
        <View>
          <Icon name="search" size = {20} color = "#4285F4" />
        </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
</View>
```

if you are not using react-native-vector-icons replace icon with .png magnifying glass image